# streaming large parsed CSV with Django StreamingHttpResponse timing out?

Tags: python, django, csv

The following code based on Django's documentation [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/outputting-csv/) works fine to parse certain years from a 400MB CSV and download through StreamingHttpResponse (for example, requesting only 2016 yields a 13MB CSV). Adding a filter parameter to return records matching certain locations (British Columbia, for example) returns only the header row.  When I edit the CSV to place a sample of British Columbia records to the top of the CSV, those are output... and then the download stops.  The test case passes, I assume this is some kind of timeout with the HTTPResponse?  Is there a keepalive option?

```
import csv
import os
import urllib
import datetime
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from STC_Arrivals import settings


class Echo(object):
def write(self, value):
    return value


def extract_years_from_csv(startyear, endyear, filter_text):
f = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + settings.CANSIM_FILE + ".csv")
reader = csv.DictReader(f)

pseudo_buffer = Echo()
writer = csv.writer(pseudo_buffer)
yield writer.writerow(reader.fieldnames)

try:
    for row in reader:
        readyears = row['Ref_Date']
        readyear = int(readyears[:4])
        if int(startyear) <= readyear <= int(endyear):
            if len(filter_text):
                search_text = row['GEO'] + row['TRAV']
                if filter_text.lower() in search_text.lower():
                    yield writer.writerow(
                        [row['Ref_Date'], row['GEO'], row['TRAV'], row['Vector'], row['Coordinate'], row['Value']])
            else:
                yield writer.writerow(
                    [row['Ref_Date'], row['GEO'], row['TRAV'], row['Vector'], row['Coordinate'], row['Value']])

except ValueError:
    pass
finally:
    f.close()


def download(request, startyear, endyear):
# if invalid years provided, return last year and current year
# if request contains an additional parameter to filter for, pass it to the extraction method.

try:
    if int(startyear) < 2005:
        startyear = datetime.datetime.now().year - 1
except ValueError:
    startyear = datetime.datetime.now().year - 1

try:
    if int(endyear) > datetime.datetime.now().year:
        endyear = datetime.datetime.now().year
except ValueError:
    endyear = datetime.datetime.now().year

filter_text = request.GET.get("filter", "")

response = StreamingHttpResponse(extract_years_from_csv(startyear, endyear, filter_text), content_type="text/csv")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="CANSIM04270001-eng-' + startyear + '-' + endyear + '.csv"'
return response

def test_extract_years_from_csv(self):

    testyear = "2016"
    filtertext = "British Columbia"

    rows = views.extract_years_from_csv(testyear, testyear, filtertext)

    for row in rows:
        try:
            readyear = int(row[:4])
            self.assertEqual(readyear, int(testyear))
            self.assertIn(filtertext, row)
        except ValueError:
            print "Conversion error"
```

Comment: What is your django stack (like nginx+uwsgi)? Have you measured how long it takes for the requests to expire, if its something like 90 seconds for every request then it's a good giveaway that it is a config setting.

Comment: Prod is old school (Godaddy) Apache / Python 2.6.6 / Django 1.4.21 but I also tried local with django server and it times out at 11-13 seconds.  I'll check through settings, thanks for that lead, but I'm still wondering if there is something I can do better with my code.  Although I hate the thought of creating temp files just so that I can obtain a content length.